# how does Istio Envoy proxy use iptables in macOS?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

As I know, macOS doesn't have iptables but has pf(packet filter) which is similar to iptables. But when I see istio-init container's log, I see istio envoy proxy is running command about initializing nat table of iptables.
the log looks like this

```html
2022-05-26T08:51:19.067180Z info    Istio iptables environment:
ENVOY_PORT=
INBOUND_CAPTURE_PORT=
ISTIO_INBOUND_INTERCEPTION_MODE=
ISTIO_INBOUND_TPROXY_ROUTE_TABLE=
ISTIO_INBOUND_PORTS=
ISTIO_OUTBOUND_PORTS=
ISTIO_LOCAL_EXCLUDE_PORTS=
ISTIO_EXCLUDE_INTERFACES=
ISTIO_SERVICE_CIDR=
ISTIO_SERVICE_EXCLUDE_CIDR=
ISTIO_META_DNS_CAPTURE=
INVALID_DROP=

2022-05-26T08:51:19.069632Z info    Istio iptables variables:
PROXY_PORT=15001
PROXY_INBOUND_CAPTURE_PORT=15006
PROXY_TUNNEL_PORT=15008
PROXY_UID=1337
PROXY_GID=1337
INBOUND_INTERCEPTION_MODE=REDIRECT
INBOUND_TPROXY_MARK=1337
INBOUND_TPROXY_ROUTE_TABLE=133
INBOUND_PORTS_INCLUDE=*
INBOUND_PORTS_EXCLUDE=15090,15021,15020
OUTBOUND_IP_RANGES_INCLUDE=*
OUTBOUND_IP_RANGES_EXCLUDE=
OUTBOUND_PORTS_INCLUDE=
OUTBOUND_PORTS_EXCLUDE=
KUBE_VIRT_INTERFACES=
ENABLE_INBOUND_IPV6=false
DNS_CAPTURE=false
DROP_INVALID=false
CAPTURE_ALL_DNS=false
DNS_SERVERS=[],[]
OUTPUT_PATH=
NETWORK_NAMESPACE=
CNI_MODE=false
EXCLUDE_INTERFACES=

2022-05-26T08:51:19.071962Z info    Writing following contents to rules file: /tmp/iptables-rules-1653555079071333887.txt2006549362
* nat
-N ISTIO_INBOUND
-N ISTIO_REDIRECT
-N ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
-N ISTIO_OUTPUT
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp --dport 15008 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 15001
-A ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 15006
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -j ISTIO_INBOUND
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp --dport 15090 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp --dport 15021 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp --dport 15020 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp -j ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ISTIO_OUTPUT
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.6/32 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -m owner --uid-owner 1337 -j ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo -m owner ! --uid-owner 1337 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1337 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -m owner --gid-owner 1337 -j ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo -m owner ! --gid-owner 1337 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner 1337 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -j ISTIO_REDIRECT
COMMIT
2022-05-26T08:51:19.072193Z info    Running command: iptables-restore --noflush /tmp/iptables-rules-1653555079071333887.txt2006549362
2022-05-26T08:51:19.097324Z error   Command error output: xtables parameter problem: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'nat'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
2022-05-26T08:51:19.097801Z error   Failed to execute: iptables-restore --noflush /tmp/iptables-rules-1653555079071333887.txt2006549362, exit status 2
```

I have questions about this.

1. What OS the envoy proxy is running?

   - I'm running k8s with minikube on M1
2. If it's running on macOS, how can it run command like iptables-restore?

   - even if macOS doesnt have iptables

have a good day

Comment: I would say it does not work, as there is no support for istio on arm64. e.g. github issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/38697

Comment: istio runs on minikube and when i checked the OS of minikube in minikube container terminal, it was ubuntu. then doesn't minikube run on ubuntu?